# Excel: if function + time values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Why doesn't this formula work?

```
=IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("00:10");"0";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("00:30");"0,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("01:00");"1";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("01:30");"1,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("02:00");"2";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("02:30");"2,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("03:00");"3";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("03:30");"3,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("04:00");"4";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("04:30");"4,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("05:00");"5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("05:30");"5,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("06:00");"6";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("06:30");"6,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("07:00");"7";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("07:30");"7,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("08:00");"8";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("08:30");"8,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("09:00");"9";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("09:30");"9,5";
IF(I7<=TIMEVALUE("10:00");"10";
"Error")))))))))))))))))))))
```

Sometimes it duplicates the score. Example: timevalue 3:30 and 4:00 both give me the number 4 eventhough 3:30 should be 3.5

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem myself - worked fine for me in excel once I'd replaced the semicolons with commas. By the way I suggest using `IFS()` for this many different logicals

Comment: I suspect it is a rounding issue.  I'm guessing what you think is `3:30` is actually a fraction of a second past, but still displayed as `3:30` due to your cell formatting.  I'd also suggest using a Lookup Table instead of a long `IF` formula.

Comment: If `=IF(I7<=TIME(0,10,0),0,IF(I7<=TIME(10,0,0),HOUR(I7)+IF(MINUTE(I7)<=30,0.5,1),"Error"))` works the same.. then it IS due to rounding error.